# Verwendung des Begriffs Baukommissionierung

Tags: terminology

Wird mit dem Begriff Baukommissionierung der Beginn eines Bauvorhabens bezeichnet? (In Österreich Bauverhandlung)
Für was wird er eigentlich verwendet?
Ist dieser Begriff umgangssprachlich noch üblich?

Comment: Also, umgangssprachlich sicher nicht …

Comment: Wo hast du den Begriff *Baukommissionierung* gehört oder gelesen? In Deutschland oder in Österreich? Ich halte das Wort nämlich für ein Wort aus dem österreichischen Beamtendeutsch, und wundere mich daher über den in Klammern gesetzten Zusatz *In Österreich Bauverhandlung*. Mein Vater war Baufachoberinspektor im Bauamt der Steiermärkischen Landesregierung, und wenn er von der Arbeit erzählt hat, war - wenn mich meine Erinnerung nicht trügt - recht häufig auch von Kommissionierungen die Rede.

Comment: Mündlich wurde der Begriff vernommen in Österreich. In der Schweiz ist er anscheinend teils noch relevant, als Baukommission. Lt. Duden "
Bau­kom­mis­si­on, die" Wortart: Substantiv, feminin. Kommission, die kontrolliert, ob ein Bau vorschriftsmäßig ausgeführt wird oder wurde.

Answer (score 5):

Mir persönlich ist (in Deutschland) dieses Wort noch nie untergekommen. Google findet [insgesamt nur rund zwanzig Treffer](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22baukommissionierung%22), alle auf österreichischen Seiten.

Ich schließe daraus, daß *Baukommissionierung* heute kein besonders verbreitetes Wort und außerhalb Österreichs gänzlich unbekannt ist. Vermutlich war es einmal ein österreichischer Rechtsbegriff, der damit bezeichnete Vorgang wurde aber umbenannt oder abgeschafft, bevor sich das Internet verbreitet hat (also vor ca. 2000). Ob er der heutigen *Bauverhandlung* entspricht, geht aus den wenigen Belegen nicht eindeutig hervor.

Comment: In Deutschland versteht man unter einer [Kommissionierung](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kommissionierung) etwas ganz anderes, das mit einer [Baukommission](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Baukommission) augenscheinlich wenig zu tun hat.

Answer (score 0):

Unter der - von mir nicht nachgeprüften - Voraussetzung, dass mit *Baukommissionierung* tatsächlich das gemeint ist, was in Österreich *Bauverhandlung* heißt:

aus [HELP.gv.at - Bauverfahren](https://www.help.gv.at/Portal.Node/hlpd/public/content/226/Seite.2260300.html):

> Je nach Bauvorhaben werden die Nachbarinnen/Nachbarn von Ihrem Bauvorhaben verständigt. Möglicherweise kann es auch zu einer **Bauverhandlung** (nicht in allen Bundesländern) kommen. Bei der Bauverhandlung wird allen involvierten Personen und Behörden Gelegenheit zur Geltendmachung ihrer Rechte und Interessen gegeben.

aus [wohnnet.at](http://www.wohnnet.at/sanierung/planung/bauverhandlung-15332):

> **Bauverhandlungen**
>   Der Zweck der Bauverhandlung besteht darin, allen jenen Personen und Behörden Gelegenheit zur Geltendmachung ihrer Rechte und rechtlichen Interessen zu geben. Treten irgendwelche Einwendungen z.B. von Anrainern auf, so ist in der Verhandlung auf eine gütliche Einigung hinzuarbeiten. Ohne Vergleichsversuch darf kein Entscheid gefällt werden.

Die Bauverhandlung ist also eine optionale Verhandlung, die stattfindet, wenn alle Pläne vorliegen, der Bau von der zuständigen Behörde aber noch nicht genehmigt wurde. Falls eine Bauverhandlung stattfindet, ist deren positiver Ausgang also eine notwendige Voraussetzung zur Erteilung einer Baubewilligung.

**Bauverhandlung** ist Amts-Deutsch. Nachdem aber Begriffe der Amtssprache fast immer auch in die Umgangssprache einfließen, wird *Bauverhandlung* (zumindest in Österreich) auch in der Umgangssprache verwendet, wenn über dieses Thema geredet ist.

Ich gehe davon aus, dass das in Deutschland weitgehend dasselbe für das Wort »Baukommissionierung« zutrifft.

Comment: help.gv.at und auch diesen Artikel kenne ich schon

Comment: Inwiefern beantwortet das dann nicht Deine Frage? Die Erklärung lässt an Deutlichkeit wenig zu wünschen übrig, wie ich finde.

Comment: OP hat nach Baukommissionierung gefragt. Ich habe den Begriff noch nie gehört, chirlus Antwort zeigt, wie unbekannt er in Deutschland ist (ob nah oder fern von Österreich scheint keine Rolle zu spielen). OP scheint auch zu wissen, was eine Bauverhandlung ist (sonst hätte OP die -kommissionierung nicht damit verglichen), demnach geht die Antwort an der Frage vorbei. –1.

Comment: @Jan: Ich vermute ja, dass mit der Kommissionierung auch ein Österreichischer Begriff gemeint ist. Das müsste der OP klarstellen. Ich habe auch im ersten Satz angeführt, unter welcher Prämisse ich meine Antwort geschrieben habe. Ich selbst zweifle aber daran, dass die Prämisse (Baukommissionierung = österr. Bauverhandlung) zutrifft, und werde da eventuell noch ein wenig recherchieren.